# Перенести элемент массива в другой элемент массива php

Tags: php

Необходимо в родительских элементах массива создать новый индекс и перенести все дочерние в него, id у каждого элемента есть, id родительского элемента также есть. Облазил уже наверно все функции php с работой с массивами, ничего не могу найти. Такое вообще возможно? Есть массив вида:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [id] => 100
    [lvl] => 1
  )
  [1] => Array(
    [id] => 101
    [parent] => 100
    [lvl] => 2
  )
  [2] => Array(
    [id] => 102
    [parent] => 101
    [lvl] => 3
  )
  [3] => Array(
    [id] => 103
    [parent] => 101
    [lvl] => 3
  )
)
```

Хочу сделать такого вида:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [id] => 100
    [lvl] => 1
    [child] => Array(
      [0] => Array(
        [id] => 101
        [parent] => 100
        [lvl] => 2
        [child] => Array(
          [0] => Array(
            [id] => 102
            [parent] => 101
            [lvl] => 3
          )
          [1] => Array(
            [id] => 103
            [parent] => 101
            [lvl] => 3
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл таки решение, не знаю на сколько правильное, но вроде рабочее. Сначала надо перегнать в новый массив весь первый уровень:

```php
foreach($Array as $old_Arr){
    if($old_Arr["lvl"] == 1){
        $old_Arr["child"] = array();
        $new_Arr[] = $old_Arr;
    }
}
```

Затем прогоняем полученный массив по индексам, попутно снова прогоняя исходный массив, и сравневаем id

```php
for($i = 0; $i < count($new_Arr); $i++){
    foreach($Array as $old_Arr){
        if($new_Arr[$i]["id"] == $old_Arr["parent"]){
            $old_Arr["child"] = array();
            $new_Arr[$i]["child"][] = $old_Arr;
        }
    }
}
```

Затем снова прогоняем полученный массив по индексам и индексам внутри child, попутно снова прогоняя исходный массив, и сравневаем id

```php
for($i = 0; $i < count($new_Arr); $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < count($new_Arr[$i]["child"]); $j++){
        foreach($Array as $old_Arr){
            if($new_Arr[$i]["child"][$j]["id"] == $old_Arr["parent"]){
                $new_Arr[$i]["child"][$j]["child"][] = $old_Arr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Данное решение думаю подойдёт, если в исходном массиве не очень много данных, поэтому не считаю его идеальным.